# can i create a sku object into a service type product?

Tags: stripe-payments

suppose i have a membership service which cost $10/month in a subscription way

but some users can not have a reusable source to make a subscription via plan api ,alternatively i will let him to do an one-time payment via order api.(at least accept one month's money)

it is the same product,same amount,difference is one is for plan,another is for order,so question is, should i create two products one is goods type(for order),one is service(for plan/subscription). or one service type product is enough?

Comment: Can't you achieve pretty much the same thing by setting the subscription billing type to `send_invoice` instead of `charge_automatically`?. https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object

Comment: you can just at least pay once even it is not a reuseable payment source, however, use send_invoice way, that means every payment is depends on invoice, even the first pay. that's not cool anyway

Answer (score 0):

As a concept in the Stripe Dashboard, product SKUs are only used for recurring plans or invoicing. Any one time purchase can just be a charge, and does not need to be associated with any "Product" within your Stripe configuration.

If the product in this case is literally just one month of the plan, then you should probably use the same Product you have specified.

If the payment method will only work once, you could do nothing, and when the first period is up, and Stripe tries to renew, the payment will fail and the subscription will be canceled.

Or, if you're positive beforehand that it should only be charged once, you could cancel the subscription right after the first payment is completed. The customer would still have an active subscription for the period they paid for, but Stripe would not try to charge them automatically when that first period expired.

Comment: thanks  for your reply. what i mean is, we have many customers from china,they used to pay via alipay or wechat, and that can not be make recurring payment. in that case, our strategy is , let the customer at least make a one-time pay at the first time,via order api. then we still setup another recurring billing plan and send user invoice,user can pay through that in the next time and further pay. so that i thought we can share use the same Product defination. one for normal subscription one for order and sku, however, i found it is impossible to add skus into a product with a service type.

Comment: so next step, i was considering to build up 2 Products,like "Vip memership(for normal subscription,service type)" and "Vip memership(for one-time payment,goods type)". customer would first pay goods type membership,  meanwhile we setup a  recurring billing plan, let them could pay in next period via invoice